# How do I use constexpr std::rotate?

Tags: c++, containers, constexpr

I fell into this by trying to unit test a simple `constexpr` rotate implementation for C++17 as the STL equivalent isn't `constexpr` until C++20.  I quickly discovered that I couldn't unit test it, nor could I on CE using the C++20 STL equivalent.

This [doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/WGaeTTxG3):

```
auto c = std::array{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
constexpr auto first = std::rotate(c.begin(), c.begin()+1, c.end());
static_assert(*first == 1);
```

> constexpr variable 'first' must be initialized by a constant expression

That's fair, the `std::rotate` call isn't operating on a `constexpr` variable.  Let's [change that](https://godbolt.org/z/KqrMfx87n):

```
constexpr auto c = std::array{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
constexpr auto first = std::rotate(c.begin(), c.begin()+1, c.end());
static_assert(*first == 1);
```

> error: read-only variable is not assignable

Oh yeah, we're supposed to be changing that var.  The only way I could get this semi-working was to move the container into a `constexpr` function and deal with the [whole conatiner at once](https://godbolt.org/z/s9Mef517E):

```
template <typename Container>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr Container rotate(Container&& c) noexcept
{
    auto next = c.begin();
    ++next;
    std::rotate(c.begin(), next, c.end());
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto result = rotate(std::array{0, 1, 2, 3, 4});
    static_assert(result[0] == 1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This obviously isn't great as it only works with rvalues (in a compile-time context) and whole ranges, but it does work.  Is this the only context that `constexpr` `std::rotate` (and similar) work?

Comment: Are you asking if you're allowed to call modifying functions on objects explicitly declared to not be modifiable? Because that's what it sounds like you're asking.

Comment: It's more the implication that the much of the newly `constexpr` algorithms are kind of useless unless you're operating on the whole container.  Even worse is that any `constexpr` algo you write to make that work (like in my example) performs terribly in a non-constexpr scenario as the lvalue is copied on return.  I guess what I'm really asking is, what I've done above can't be what the STL designers had in mind for constexpr algos - so how am I supposed to use them?

Comment: "*much of the newly constexpr algorithms are kind of useless unless you're operating on the whole container*" Nonsense. You could be in a constexpr function, create a stack array based on some parameters (which is not `constexpr`), then pass any iterators from that array into `rotate`. The result of all of this could be returned, and that result need not be an array. And so long as the result is used in a constant expression context, you get to do it all at compile time.